# Setting up multilingual site with sitefinity in the form of mysite.com/us/home, mysite.com/fr/home

Tags: multilingual, sitefinity

Trying to set up a multilingual site with sitefinity.

The structure is

```
mysite.com/us/ - all US content
mysite.com/fr/ - all French content
```

So, the home page for the US would be at

```
mysite.com/us/home
```

and the home page for France would be at

```
mysite.com/fr/home
```

How can I do that?

Site search should be limited to the currently selected locale (/fr/ or /us/ in this example).

What happens by default is that the US home page ends up in the root of the site, and the French under /fr/:

```
mysite.com/home     #US version, should appear under mysite.com/us/home
mysite.com/fr/home  #French version
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the languages you would like to support by going to Administration->Settings and then select "Languages" from the menu on the left.

Here is a video that goes into more detail.
[Enabling and Creating Multilingual Sitefinity Pages and Content](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0qHyc0RwGk)

Comment: I've already added a language exactly as outlined in the video. Unfortunately the settings do not allow me to change the routing for the default language. So, instead of mysite.com/us/home I get mysite.com/home, as explained in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a 'dummy' default language which would route to mysite.com/home and then add US and FR as secondary languages.  Then in mysite.com/home you could add some logic to decide which language folder homepage to route to, or simply add something like this in the page html to auto redirect to the US homepage:

```
<script>
    window.location.replace('mysite.com/us/home');
</script>
```